# Eclipse Crashing when Associating External Editors

Tags: java, eclipse, scenebuilder

I've recently been attempting to set up SceneBuilder but suddenly my copy of Eclipse crashes pretty much instantly when I attempt to try and associate any external editor with a file type (not just XFXML). I've done some research and [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494261) seems to be the only page I can find talking about the issue, but I'm not sure how to take the advice therein.

I've linked the [error log](https://pastebin.com/qGYT9H8K) generated by these crashes. If anyone has experience something similar or has any idea how to go about troubleshooting this issue I'd greatly appreciate your input!

```
//I've included this code block to allow the pastebin link to work. There have
not been any issues with programming as the IDE won't operate as expected.
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: From various websites I thought it might have something to do with my PATH variable, so I went in and confirmed sys32 was the first in the list of PATH lookups. I've also installed and replicated the issue in a fresh install of eclipse, so it appears to be something now associated with my machine and not in the program itself as far as I can determine.

Comment: okay in that case, you can't fine answers in stackoverflow. I'm sorry.

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use? In the log I found the path ...`\java-neon2\`... (Neon.2 = 4.6.2) but the bug you refer to has been fixed later in Oxygen (4.7.0). The actual version is Photon (4.8.0).

Comment: @howlger you hit the nail on the head. Can't believe I forgot to update. Saved me some serious heart ache. Been busy working on this but wanted to express my gratitude even if it is late.